# visualforce + jquery

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to implement a jquery gallery plugin in a force.com site. I have uploaded a zip file containing all the required files as a static resource.

I am referencing the style sheets and javascript as below:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryadgallery, 'jquerygallery/jquery.ad-gallery.js')}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jqueryadgallery, 'jquerygallery/jquery.ad-gallery.css')}"/>
```

This works and I am getting the associated CSS for the plugin(check it out here - http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/). But the only part that's working is the image thumbnails are being displayed with the image border defined in the CSS file. You can see what I have done here - http://fusedev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/ImageDemo. I have followed the documentation but it seems to me the JavaScript isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few things to check:

- Salesforce uses prototype.js, which like jQuery, uses the global variable `$`. It's always best to do something like `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` at the top of your script in order to prevent jQuery from clobbering prototype. You'll also need to change all your javascript to use `$j` instead of `$` for jQuery stuff.
- It looks like your jquery plugin script is getting loaded before jQuery itself. Make sure your first `apex:includeScript` loads jQuery.
- My browser is reporting a syntax error in your VF page: [image]

Comment: cheers jeremy, but I already have the jquery.noConflict(). The error is due to me still playing around with it, its fixed now. And I have moved the include script above the plugin script but still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your JS has multiple very basic syntax errors. Start by matching your brackets.

Comment: cheers jeremy it turned out I had missed some javascript and left it as $. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, '/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, '/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js')}"/>

<script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    if(j$){
        alert('Success');
    }else{
        alert('Failure');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain your example?

Comment: I don't think you can solve this issue by prompting user about multiple jQuery exists.

Comment: First, you have to upload your jquery zip file to a static resource. If you are following this method you need to point to 2 files they are jquery.js and jquery-ui.min.js. we are using no conflict because there were different meanings for $ in visual force and jquery. Here alert message says if your code works fine then it will display success and if not it will display failure. why are we using this success and failure messages? In salesforce, there is no other way to validate the javascript in visual force pages.